# How to fix: CMake-defined macro won't be received by compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, symbols

**SOLVED!** `=` **instead of** `-` **in the CMakeLists.txt in** `say-hello` **directory**

I have problems with defining a preprocessor variable with CMake according to vector-of-bool's CMake-Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYgESCQeGJY&list=PLK6MXr8gasrGmIiSuVQXpfFuE1uPT615s&index=8.
Obviously, I am using a different CMake-Version than the one that he's using in the video. But before changing my version I want to tackle the problem here.

After configuring successfully via `cmake ..`, I run `make` and receive the following:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/src/say-hello/hello.cpp.o
<command-line>:0:14: warning: ISO C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name
/home/maximilian/Dokumente/02_Programmieren/VSCMAKE/say-hello/src/say-hello/hello.cpp: In function ‘void hello::say()’:
<command-line>:0:17: error: expected ‘;’ before numeric constant
/home/maximilian/Dokumente/02_Programmieren/VSCMAKE/say-hello/src/say-hello/hello.cpp:7:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘HELLO_VERSION’
         std::cout << "Hello (Version " << HELLO_VERSION << ")\n";
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/src/say-hello/hello.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/src/say-hello/hello.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: recipe for target 'say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [say-hello/CMakeFiles/say-hello.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am using:

- Linux
- g++ 8.1
- C++11
- CMake 3.14.4
- Visual Studio Code

Top CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.4)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(say-hello)
add_subdirectory(mainsrc)
```

CMakeLists.txt in mainsrc

```
add_executable(main.out main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main.out PRIVATE say-hello)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <say-hello/hello.hpp>

int main(){
    hello::say();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt in say-hello

```
add_library(say-hello
            src/say-hello/hello.cpp
            src/say-hello/hello.hpp
            )

target_include_directories(say-hello PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

target_compile_definitions(say-hello PUBLIC HELLO_VERSION-4)
```

hello.hpp

```
#ifndef HELLO
#define HELLO

//#define SAYHELLOVERSION 4

namespace hello{
    void say();
}

#endif
```

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.hpp"

namespace hello{
    void say(){
        //int version = SAYHELLOVERSION;
        std::cout << "Hello (Version " << HELLO_VERSION << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `HELLO_VERSION-4` is invalid. You meant `HELLO_VERSION=4` ? Don't you get at least a `warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name` ?

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks, that's it.